# Revoke Delete privilege (There is no such grant defined for user)

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-revoke

I am trying to revoke the `Delete` on mysql user

I used this code

```
  REVOKE DELETE
   ON *.*
   FROM 'sample_user'@'%';
```

But this returns me something like this

> **Error Code: 1141.** *There is no such grant defined for user*

Is it possible to revoke it? Currently I have this privileges

```
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW 
  DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, 
 CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CR...
```

I just want to remove the `Delete` Privilege

Comment: what your see if execute query `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'sample_user'@'%'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you applied the All privileges permissions at the `database.*` level.
You cannot only Revoke privileges at the `database.*` level as the All privileges was not simply carried down to the individual tables.

Try to wiped privileges at the database level all together.
And then, you able to Grant and Revoke them on a table basis.

The effect of `REVOKE` statement depends on the privilege level:

**Global level**
The changes take effect when the user account connects to the MySQL Server in the subsequent sessions. The changes are not applied to all currently connected users.

**Database level**
The changes take effect after the next USE statement.

**Table and column levels**
The changes take effect on all subsequent queries.